# Get entire substring after 2nd occurrences of a delimiter including delimiter

Tags: java

I have a string(s) ( NOT `Path` or `File`-path ) like below:

```
String str1 = "/first/second/third/fourth/fifth";
String str2 = "/foo/bar/blah";
```

GIVEN: The string will always start with leading slash and there are guaranteed minimum two slashes (can be more too, as above) and some substring after that.

Now I am trying to capture the entire substring `"after-first-two-slashes"`. So that my output becomes:

```
Output:
str1_becomes = /second/third/fourth/fifth
str2_becomes = /bar/blah
```

Please note that I want to retain the leading slash too. What efficient approach should I follow to achieve it? Need some directions/clues as feeling lost here. Preferably java 1.8+ based.

Comment: What inefficient approach have you already implemented? What was inefficient about it?

Comment: Assuming it always starts with a forward slash: `str = str.replaceFirst("/.*?/", "/");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do this using simple string operations.

If the string always begins with a slash and has two slashes, you could just use indexOf for finding the second slash's position:

```
str1.indexOf('/',1);
```

This looks for the first slash starting with the second character.

After that, you can use substring for getting tje resulting string (starting with the index you just found out):

```
str1.substring(str1.indexOf('/',1));
```

If the first slash is not necessarily the first character, you can search for the first slash using indexOf and use that result +1 as the start index for searching the second slash:

```
str1.substring(str1.indexOf('/',str1.indexOf('/')));
```

Comment: as the "length of substrings in between can be huge", then this approach will be faster than the replaceFirst (which uses regex inside).

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for the explanation.  It is exactly I was looking for. Quick question though - Performance wise how it compares to - `str.replaceFirst("/.*?/", "/")` ?

Comment: It will likely be faster because it just does an index search (stopping as soon as it finds the index) and buildimg the resulting String (needs to be done using the regex, too). Regexes are a nice tool but come with a bit of an overhead (for parsing the regex, regexes need to be able to do more, etc.). I don't believe this could be done significantly) more performant (except if you just e.g. expect a `CharSequence` as the result and not a `String`).